# tf serving deploy two models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have two different tensorflow models A and B,  the output of model A will be feeded into model B as input.  both of them need to be deployed with tf serving.  I need to call twice with grpc or http requet to get output of model B.

Does tf serving support only one grpc or http request to get output of model B?

Comment: I don't think so, you need to merge your model in TensorFlow and export it as a single model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIC, tensorflow serving does not support pipeline mode. But I think you could merge A and B into one model.